# Running a proxy server authenticated from a database

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, proxy

I want to set up a proxy server service from one of my servers. But I need to be able to authenticate users of the service via a remote MSSQL database. It would useful if I could track usage for the purpose of enforcing bandwidth restrictions too.

Can anyone suggest a good (maybe out of the box) solution for doing this? Or even a codeable way of managing requests a proxy server. So I could write it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain where your proxy is going to sit in relation to the users?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The users will be anyone, across the globe. And the server is in the UK.

Comment: Does it have to be Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Not necessarily, I suppose. Just an authentication system that can be edited easily via a web application.

Answer (score 1):

Since it doesn't have to be Microsoft SQL Server, and if you're ok with Linux, I'd recommend Squid Proxy: it's mature, stable, scales reasonably well, and supports a wide variety of authentication methods (LDAP, MySQL, NTLM to name a few) and deployment scenarios.  Plus it's open source, so you don't have to invest anything up front.